# Iosでの輝度操作がうまくいかない

Tags: objective-c

Object-cで以下を実現したいと考えています。

1. 特定画面(以下、画面Aと記載。)で輝度を最大にし、別画面遷移で元の輝度に戻したい
2. 画面Aでホームボタンを押してバッググランドにまわすと、輝度を元の輝度に戻し、アプリを再びフォアグラウンドに戻して画面Aを表示させると輝度を最大にする
3. 画面Aで端末の電源ボタンを押して、再び電源ボタンを押してロックを解除して画面Aを表示させても輝度を最大にする

上記1はうまくいったのですが、objectivecの経験が浅く、2、3の具体的な実装方法が分からず悩んでおります。
もしどのように実装すればよいかご存じの方がいらしたら、サンプルコードや参考になるurlをご教示ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIApplicationDelegate`プロトコルには

- `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;`
- `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;`
- `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;`
- `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;`

というメソッドがあるので、プロジェクトの中の`AppDelegate.h/m`またはその名前を変更したクラスの中で適切な（多分、`DidBecomeActive`と`WillResignActive`）を定義し、そのメソッド内で輝度を調整すれば良いと思います